Scalar ASP.NET Core 8 Web API - deploy to IIS
I have a problem when deploying an ASP.NET Core Web API to my IIS. I can't access scalar UI using '/scalar/v1' everything just white.
When I run it locally, everything is ok, I can test my API directly or using Postman. It just happens when deploying to IIS.
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(options =>
    {
        options.RouteTemplate = "/openapi/{documentName}.json";        
    });
    app.MapScalarApiReference(options =>
    {
        options.Title = "My - API";        
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


I tried to include and remove the environment checking since this was checked as an answer but I'm still having the same problem
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
//{
    app.UseSwagger(options =>
    {
        options.RouteTemplate = "/openapi/{documentName}.json";        
    });
    app.MapScalarApiReference(options =>
    {
        options.Title = "CPS - API";        
    });
//}


You should remove Swagger and add MapOpenApi. Use something like this
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapOpenApi();
    app.MapScalarApiReference(options =>
    {
        options
            .WithTitle("CPS - API");
    });
}

Note: This is tested in .NET 9 only
